# How can I change this for loop to a for_each loop?

Tags: c++

How can I convert this to a [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) loop?

```
template <typename Container>
void draw_all(const Container &c, const rectangle &w)
{
    complex<double> bl, tr;
    bl = w.get_bl();
    tr = w.get_tr();

    for (typename Container::const_iterator p= c.begin(); p != c.end(); p++)
    {
        if((*p)->inside_window(bl,tr))
            (*p)->draw();
    }
}
```

I'm trying this: `for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), w.inside_window(w.get_bl(),w.get_tr()));`

I get errors: assing 'const rectangle' as 'this' argument of 'virtual bool rectangle::inside_window(const std::complex&, const std::complex&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

**edit: inside window()**

```
bool rectangle::inside_window(const complex<double> &_bl, const complex<double> &_tr)
{
    if(_bl.real() > bl.real() || _tr.real() > tr.real() || _bl.imag() > bl.imag() || _tr.imag() > tr.imag())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;

    cout.flush();
}
```

for_each():

```
template<typename InputIter, typename UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIter first, InputIter last, UnaryFunction fn)
{
    while (first != last)
        fn(* first++); // Increment first but dereference its old value.
    return fn;
}
```

Comment: is rectangle::inside_window() declared const?

Comment: @jzila i've added inside_window()

Comment: Yup, as I suspected. It needs to be const, but someone else already gave you that answer before you responded to my comment.

Comment: There’s no need for the `if (x) return false; else return true;` (just `return !x;` suffices) and the `cout.flush()` doesn’t make sense in that method. Not your fault, but…I pity you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `rectangle::inside_window()` as a `const` method:

```
virtual bool inside_window(const std::complex&, const std::complex&) const;
                                                                  // ^^^^^
```

This makes `this` of type `const rectangle*` rather than just `rectangle*`, which allows `inside_window()` to be called on a `const rectangle`, as it must be in `for_each()`.

However, your logic is flawed: if you want to *test* the result of `inside_window()` and conditionally call `draw()`, then the only way to do that with `for_each()` is with a helper method, either as a functor:

```
struct draw_visible : public std::unary_function<rectangle, void> {

    const std::complex<double> bl, tr;

    draw_visible(const std::complex<double>& bl, const std::complex<double> tr)
        : bl(bl), tr(tr) {}

    void operator()(const rectangle& r) const {
        if (r.inside_window(bl, tr))
            r.draw();
    }

};

template<class Container>
void draw_all(const Container& c, const rectangle& w) {
     std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), draw_visible(w.get_bl(), w.get_tr()));
}
```

Or as a lambda:

```
template<class Container>
void draw_all(const Container& c, const rectangle& w) {
    std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [&w](const rectangle& r) {
        if (r.inside_window(w.get_bl(), w.get_tr())
            r.draw();
    });
}
```

Furthermore, you probably shouldn’t be using `std::complex` to model points. A custom structure would be more semantically appropriate:

```
// A basic mutable 2D double vector.
struct point {
    double x, y;
};
```

Comment: i don't get it. what happend to draw_all? i have added my for_each to the original post. is draw_visible supposed to beinside draw_all()?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I'd say inside_window is not a const method, that's why you're getting that error. Can you show us the code for that?

You've declared p to be const, meaning you're promising not to change anything using it. But your inside_window() method does not promise not to do that, hence the compile is saying you're not honouring that promise. Make inside_window const and this should go away (if indeed you don't change anything inside that method, then it'll be an easy fix)

Comment: added inside_window to original post

Comment: add const to the end of the definition; see Jon Purdy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to for_each needs to be a function. More specifically, a function that receives `*p` and does the body of that for loop of yours

```
/* function or method */ (const Container& c){
   if(c->inside_window(cl, tr))
     c->draw();
}
```

But notice how we need to keep track of `cl` and `tr` for out function. The way to have this work is to make the function the `operator ()` overload of an object that has `cl` and `tr` as instance variables.

```
class Drawer{
    complex<double> bl, tr;
    Drawer(/*constructor parameters, probably w*/){ /*...*/}
    void operator() (const Container& c){ /*...*/ }
};

for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), Drawer(w));
```

Comment: I am sorry i do not understand this can you explain i am a beginner

Comment: @user521180: err, what don't you understand specifically?

Comment: the first bit of code.. where is that from? why isnt rectangle in the signature? i dont understand what i have to do to fix it

Comment: In the first bit of code the `...` are pseudocode, sorry. Rectangle is not in the signature because for_each will only pass one argument corresponding to the loop iterator. This is why we have to turn the function into a method and make the rectangle related stuff into instance variables (so they can be accessed without being passed as parameters).